# Compare rows and return column that matches with all the record (POSTGRESQL)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I have a table (tbl_customer)

```
id | name   | birthday | address  | gender
-------------------------------------------
1  | JOSEPH | 19920413 | NEW YORK | M
2  | JAKE   | 19920413 | LONDON   | M
3  | JOHN   | 19920413 | GERMANY  | M
```

then I need a query that will compare all records in this table then return columns that is identical to all the records..for the example above result should be:

```
 birthday | gender
-------------------
 19920413 | M
 19920413 | M
 19920413 | M
```

or much better if the result should look something like this..

```
 column_name | value
--------------------------
 birthday    | 19920413 
 gender      | M
```

thanks :)

Comment: What code isn't working or what code have you been testing for that?

Comment: @HanselF.  I have not started any code yet..

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you want? E.g. you want to return a column name (and its distinct value) if and only if the column has exactly one distinct value in the table? How do you want to deal with NULLs?

Comment: hi @verbatross , the result should return the list of columns whose values are identical/ same among all rows. all above mentioned fields/columns are set as NOT NULL, so there is no way that null will be inserted on tables

Comment: the comparison is per column.. for ex in address column, it will check if all values under the column are the same.. then it will return that column name as result

Comment: It sounds like you want to perform [relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). If so, a pertinent question is, with or without remainder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) extension and [`plpgsql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html):

```
create function foo(out f_name text, out f_value text) returns setof record language plpgsql immutable as $$
declare
  h hstore;
  r hstore := null;
  n text[];
begin
  for h in select hstore(t.*) from tbl_customer as t loop
    if r is null then
      r := h;
    else
      /* -- To ignore NULLs so the null values does not affects to the result
      select array_agg(key) into n from each(r) where value is null;
      r := r || coalesce(slice(h, n), '');
      select array_agg(key) into n from each(h) where value is null;
      h := h || coalesce(slice(r, n), '');
      */ -- I believe that there is much more elegant solution is possible 
      r := r - akeys(r - h);
      exit when r = '';
    end if;
  end loop;
  raise info '%', r;
  return query select * from each(r);
end $$;

select * from foo();

INFO:  "gender"=>"M", "birthday"=>"19920413"
╔══════════╤══════════╗
║  f_name  │ f_value  ║
╠══════════╪══════════╣
║ gender   │ M        ║
║ birthday │ 19920413 ║
╚══════════╧══════════╝
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I have not run it yet since I got an error in hstore.. do you know how to install it on windows??

Comment: @john1717 `create extension hstore with schema public;`

Comment: this one is correct .. thanks.. but do you know how can I handle null? just in case there's column that can accept null?

Comment: @john1717 It is depending on how do you want to handle nulls: just ignore; null = null; null <> null.

Answer (score 0):

Static code solution

```
select      (array ['id','name','birthday','address','gender'])[pos] as column_name
           ,min(val)                                                 as value

from        t cross join
              unnest(array [id::varchar(10),name,birthday::varchar(10),address,gender]) with ordinality u(val,pos)

group by    pos

having      (   count (distinct val) = 1
            and count(*) = count (val)
            )
        or  count (val) = 0
```

Comment: but is there a way that I will not indicate each columns.. ??

Comment: @john1717, only with dynamic SQL therefore the "static code"

Answer (score -2):

```
select * 
from tbl_customer 
where birthday in (
    select birthday 
    from tbl_customer 
    group by birthday 
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion/answer... is there a way that I don't need to indicate each columns in where clause??

Comment: thanks.. may I know whose that person? and how to contact him?

Comment: Down-voted (1) this is not even remotely close to an answer to the question (2) This is not MySQL. Postgres has analytic functions.